# Is it possible to make a visual basic app and connect to mysql database without server? (Just like microsoft access file)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Is it possible to have a mysql database without opening xampp or mysql workbench?

Comment: Xampp and MySQL workbench are not needed, but you do need MySQL server. So no. There are other solutions that fit better.

Comment: What other solutions do you suggest? a database like access

Comment: SQLite would be an option if your looking for a db file.

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you are trying to achieve..